# Mock Spring's MessageSource.getMessage method

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock Spring's `MessageSource.getMessage` method but `Mockito` it is complaining with an unhelpful message, I am using:

```
when(mockMessageSource.getMessage(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(Locale.class)))
    .thenReturn(anyString());
```

The error message is:

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:

when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());

verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods 
that cannot be mocked Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()
/hashCode().
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is that `anyString()` is the matcher it is complaining about when it is used as a parameter in your `thenReturn(...)` call. If you don't care what's returned, just return an empty String a la `thenReturn("")`.

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer has the fix for the code in the question, I'd like to note that it is not necessary to use a mock library just to create a `MessageSource` that always returns an empty string.

The following code does the same:

```
MessageSource messageSource = new AbstractMessageSource() {
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        return new MessageFormat("");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, one thing looks strange to me:

You are returning `Mockito.anyString()` this is a `Matcher`.

I think you must return a concrete String.

```
when(mockMessageSource.getMessage(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(Locale.class)))
.thenReturn("returnValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you need to return some actual object matching the return type of the method from your mock.
Compare with:

```
when(mockMessageSource.getMessage(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(Locale.class))).
thenReturn("A Value that I care about, or not");
```

The larger issue this points to is that you're really not testing any behavior. You might want to consider what value this test is providing. Why mock the object in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by only spying the MessageSource (so I still can verify the getMessage call later) and setting the flag '`useCodeAsDefaultMessage`' to true.
In this case a fallback mechanism from the `AbstractMessageSource#getMessage` will do its job and just return the supplied key as message.

```
messageSource = spy(new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource());
messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

getMessage method on class ResourceBundleMessageSource is final

Answer (score 1):

```
Mockito.when(messageSource.getMessage(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(Locale.class))).thenReturn("Error Message");
```

this will help you